# Can I convert my Dell NX3000 server to a disk-based storage device?

Tags: backup, storage

I'd like to go away from tape backups if possible, so I'm wondering how I can go about converting this dedicated NAS server into something I can use to hold the backups of my new file server. If it is possible, how do I configure it? Do I need to reformat the disks or can I keep the current OS on there? Do I have to delete the file partitions as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have that model in some customer' site. They use two method;

- BackupExec with to Disk option.
- BackupExec System Recovery's image from the server I want to backup dumping in a folder on the NX3000.

So it depend on the tool you have for the backup, but for your answer, yes, you can use it as a backup's destination.

Edited: I kept the 2008 from Dell on them, I used the NAS Share from the D:\, as by default it came with the disk partitioned with the big partition on d:.

Just be sure to plan a off-site backup, as your library offer you that, but not a disk storage.